# Как изменить меню CSS?

Tags: css

Как сместить вниз ссылки в меню?

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:auto;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:133px;
  font-size:.6em;
  background:#000 repeat-x top left;
  font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
     
ul.menu li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
     
ul.menu li a {
  float:left;
  color:#A79787;
  text-decoration:none;
  height:24px;
  padding:9px 15px 0;
  font-weight:normal;
}
     
ul.menu li a:hover,.current {
  color:#fff;
  background:#000 repeat-x top left;
  text-decoration:none;
}
     
ul.menu .current a {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:700;
}
     
ul.menu{
  background-color:#000;
}

ul.menu li a:hover, .menu li.current {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

```html
<body>    
  <ul class="menu">    
    <li><a href="#" title="">Home</a></li>    
    <li class="current"><a href="#" title="">Products</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#" title="" >Downloads</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#" title="">Contact</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#" title="">About Us</a></li>    
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Вниз все меню или только ссылки относительно точек?

Comment: только ссылки,мне нужно место в левом углу под логотип,а там само меню

Comment: А вообще обычно это по другому делается. Сначала делаете ширину фона одинаковым с меню, а потом размещаете этот код под шапкой. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить после

```
border:1px solid #000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

строку

```
PADDING-TOP: Zpx;
```

Z - это число в пикселях.

Конечный результат:

```
border:1px solid #000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
PADDING-TOP: Zpx;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ul.menu li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:100px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
```